# How to set Widget as Anchor content in GWT instead of the usual String?

Tags: gwt, hyperlink, widget, anchor, gxt

I'm in a situation where I want a whole Widget to be a link to another page. Both `Anchor` and `Hyperlink` only accept Strings or `SafeHTML` as visual representation. However, I need e.g. a `<div>...</div>` to be a link.

This would be similar to:

```
<a href="somesite"><div><p>This whole thing is a link</p></div></a>
```

Is there a way to do this withou custom coding my own SafeHTML? To be more concrete, I want a GXT `HBoxLayoutContainer` to be clickable and bookmarkable.

Comment: you mean you need a panel which i clickable ?ofcourse link will be inside the panel.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be using UiBinder:

```xml
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
  xmlns:container="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container">

 ...
 <g:HTMLPanel>
     <a href="somesite">
       <container:HBoxLayoutContainer>...</container:HBoxLayoutContainer>
     </a>
 </g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am populating the HBoxLayoutContainer as well as the panel/container around it dynamically in my .java file by looping through Lists.. so I am unable to choose the declarative path you mentioned above. :-(

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Connect your panels with Java code using "@UiField", maybe with "@UiField(provided=true)". Instead of using `<container:HBoxLayoutContainer>` in the ui.xml file, you can also just declare it as a `<g:Widget>` and then set anything you want from outside.

Comment: HTMLPanel and the like will not accept custom Widgets as their children, though. I get the following error:

Not allowed in an HTML context: <g:Widget ui:field='linkedWidget'>

And I have it declared like so:

`<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
 xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

 <g:Anchor ui:field="link">
  <g:Widget ui:field="linkedWidget"/>
 </g:Anchor>
</ui:UiBinder>`

Comment: The problem isn't HTMLPanel. But you can't use `<g:Anchor>` here. Use `<a ui:field="link">` instead (and connect it to an AnchorElement field in your class).